# How can I save images without using GDI+?

Tags: c#, image-processing, gdi+

I have big problems when using GDI+ with saving very large images (100 - 200Mb).

I didn't find any good library (LGPL, BSD) for saving images. Do you have any recommendations ?

It is possible to write something on my own without using GDI+ ? And if yes, where I should dig?

The question is not how to get rid of errors!

Questions are:

1) can I write image saving to TIFF and JPEG not using GDI+?

2) are there some LGPL, BSD libraries with this opportunity?

Comment: What problems do you have with GDI+?

Comment: I'm getting Out of Memory Exception.

Comment: What formats do you need to support?

Comment: @ieaglle Edit your question with details (errors, image format,..) so people here can help you solve your problem.

Comment: have you ever found an answer to your question? i have similar issue.

Comment: @Zafar, I switched to http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/ and it seems to be working.

Comment: can that lib make a save operation, like `Image.Save()` in GDI+?

Comment: @Zafar, look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16308762/183267 to see an example.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [Independent JPEG Group library](http://www.ijg.org/) since back in the days of DOS, and I know it can handle images that are larger than the available memory.

Comment: I just realized that the question asks for a C# solution not C, but I believe there's a way to call a C library from C#?